# azure websocket connection through kubernetes, many disconnects with code 1006

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, disconnect

A nodejs server on kubernetes get many websocket connections - all is fine, but from time to time an abrupt disconnect occurs (code 1006).

Then every few minutes, the server disconnects from all clients (all disconnects have code 1006).

Important to note that this happens to all replicas at the same time, indicating the cause is external to the servers (and the clients). Could it be the application gateway?

How can I debug this further?

Comment: What is your ingress setup? Have you looked at the logs in the ingress proxies?

Comment: the default application gateway of azure. there are 502 errors on the logs there, but I don't see any indication to that on the nodejs server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from the default azure application gateway to nginx solved this problem.